# C# Emgu.Cv.Matrix<Float> to int

Tags: c#, computer-vision, emgucv

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Emgu.CV.Matrix' to 'int'

Anyone can help me?

i have tried to Convert.ToInt16(rsmmatrixtanimlayici) it's not working.

Comment: http://i.hizliresim.com/9G09Mo.jpg

matrixuzaklik is Single

matrixuzaklik = new Matrix<Single>(rsmmatrixtanimlayici, enyakinkomsu);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 matrixuzaklik = new Matrix<Single>(rsmmatrixtanimlayici.Rows, enyakinkomsu);
```